# ionic 4 - can't set custom attribute tags

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm trying to set custom attributes in a tag inside a `ngFor` loop.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let a of this.current_items?.areas; let i = index">
  ...
```

My attempts:

```
<div class="productBatchArea" custom-data='{{ a.title }}'>
// ERROR: Can't bind to 'custom-data' since it isn't a known property of 'div'

<div class="productBatchArea" [data-teste]="a.title">
// ERROR: Can't bind to 'data-teste' since it isn't a known property of 'div'

<div class="productBatchArea" data-teste="{{ a.title }}">
// ERROR:  Can't bind to 'teste' since it isn't a known property of 'div'
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try like this

```
[attr.custom-data]="a.title"
```

Please let me know if it is not working